# REGEX match // but not ://

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and trying to learn it. I am writing code in Coffeescript and want to match // for comments but not :// so it does not change the color of links. This is for a grammar file for atom text editor. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if Coffeescript supports it, but it's a case for negated lookbehind : `(?<!:)//`

Comment: Atom grammar files should support lookbehinds as they are Oniguruma powered. So, `(?<!:)//` should work.

Comment: @Aaron Coffeescript compiles to plain Javascript and doesn't have its own regex implementation. Yes, it supports it.

Comment: @Aaron that works thinks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

The most easiest pattern I could come up with is by using a negative look behind like this:

```
(?<!:)//
```

But look behinds are not supported by javascript (not sure about Atom itself, but Sublime supports it), so what I could think of is by using a regex like this:

```
.*:\/\/.*|(\/\/.*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qcxG13/1)**

The idea is to use the discard technique, so the pattern will intentionally match what you don't want but will capture what you actually want. Then you have to grab the content from the capturing group.

Match information:

```
Group 1.    11-26   `// some comment`
Group 1.    41-59   `// another comment`
```